# No hay data cuando intento a convertir UIImage a PNG Data en SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift

Tengo este código dónde intento a convertir `UIImage` a PNG Data con `uiimage.pngData()` cuando aparece un `View` cuando empiezo el app.

```
print(uiimage.pngData())

.onAppear {
    if let data = uiimage.pngData() { ... }
}
```

En el print sí aparece la data pero la condicional no ejecuta. ¿Por qué es así?

Comment: Puse dentro de las llave del `if` `print("yes")` y si funciona.

Comment: Si, lo intento y no funciona :[... no se porque

Answer (score 0):

En el código que tienes no sé si haces un unwrap directamente de la imagen en otro lado; que no es lo recomendable y debería marcarte error en esta línea:

```
if let data = uiimage.pngData() { ... }//uiimage es optional
```

Intenté este código con una imagen de nombre *"fondo.png"* y otra *"fondo1.jpeg"* en los `Assets`. Con ambas imágenes funciona:

```
.onAppear() {
    //La manera segura de no hacer unwrap de opcionales es usar guard
    guard let uiimage = UIImage(named: "fondo") else { return }
                
    if let data = uiimage.pngData() {
        print("yes")//Imprime yes
    } else {
        print("no")
    }
}
```